# Custom validator for file upload in primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I want to write a custom validator for advance file upload where i can check the size of file and throw a validation message if its greater than the maximum size.
But, validator is never called. Can, anyone please help?

Comment: look at this post (I mean do it like it is explained) [File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)  and for the size look at the primefaces upload page [Primefaces Size](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml)

Comment: I want to show a validation error if the combined size of multiple files is greater then maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

The file size that you upload with `p:fileUplaod` is unlimited by default, to set a limit in size you can use `sizeLimit`, if you uplaod a file which the size is greater then the limit an error message will showup. you can read more about it in the Primefaces web site [Primefaces Upload File](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml).

Comment: that sizeLimit is for a single file, I want to calculate the size of all the files and then see if that size is greater than the maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at this post [Upload File Step by Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964) to learn how to upload a file, and for the size limit you only need to check for all file size it will look like this :

```
Long size;
Long sizeLimite = 100000 ;
List<FileUploadEvent> e = new ArrayList<>();
```

and for each FileUploadEvent :

```
size = eventUpload.getFile().getSize() + size;
e.add(eventUpload);
```

and in the end :

```
if(size < sizeLimite ) {
 executUpload(e);
}
else{
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(" NO GOOD SIZE"));
}
```

In the example i gave you it's a loop you only have to copy it and make the first to check for the size, and the second to execute the upload method if the condition is true.

Comment: I called two method from the command button with the use of remote command.One is for file upload and one is for submitting data. I calculated the size and if size is greater i stored the Faces message. I want to show that message on xhtml without calling the other method for submitting data.

Comment: i will update my answer

Comment: is it what do you look for ?!? @user5268

Comment: In my form, file upload is not necessary, so i called second method from remote command. So, the problem is that Faces message is coming but just after that it calls second method. I want it to behave like a validator.

Comment: you can avoid use the remote command i will update my answer to clear this point

Comment: did you try oncomplete ?!?

Comment: oncomplete of command button i called file upload listener and submit form methods.Before oncomplete of command button it should pass all the validators, so, i want to check this size functionality of file before oncomplete of command button.

Comment: any evolution anything new  ?!?